# Python - Return top 5 words with highest frequency

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, frequency

As the title says, I need to write a code that returns a list of 5 words (from an input string) that have the highest frequency. This is what I have so far:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def top5_words(text):
  tally = defaultdict(int)
  words = text.split()

  for word in words:
    if word in tally:
      tally[word] += 1
    else:
      tally[word] = 1

  answer = sorted(tally, key=tally.get, reverse = True)

  return(answer)
```

For example if you input: top5_words("one one was a racehorse two two was one too") it should return: ["one", "two", "was", "a", "racehorse"] but instead it returns: ['one', 'was', 'two', 'racehorse', 'too', 'a'] - does anyone know why this is?

EDIT:

This is what I've got now thanks to Anand S Kumar:

```
import collections

def top5_words(text):

  counts =  collections.Counter(text.split())

  return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(),key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))[:5]]
```

Comment: Dicts don't have any order, for words with same count the order can be anything. Plus your expected output doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Appearance count- one : 3, was : 2, two: 2, racehorse: 1, too: 1, a: 1. It looks like you need to tie break in alphabetical order.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and then you can use its method - [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) . Example -

```
import collections
def top5_words(text):
    counts = collections.Counter(text.split())
    return counts.most_common(5)
```

Please note, above returns a list of 5 tuples, and in each tuple, first element is the actual word and the second element the count of that word.

Demo -

```
>>> import collections
>>> def top5_words(text):
...     counts = collections.Counter(text.split())
...     return counts.most_common(5)
...
>>> top5_words("""As the title says, I need to write a code that returns a list of 5 words (from an input string) that have the highest frequency. This is what I have so far""")
[('that', 2), ('a', 2), ('I', 2), ('the', 2), ('have', 2)]
```

---

If you just want the elements and not the count , then you can also use list comprehension to take that information. Example -

```
import collections
def top5_words(text):
    counts = collections.Counter(text.split())
    return [elem for elem, _ in counts.most_common(5)]
```

Demo -

```
>>> import collections
>>> def top5_words(text):
...     counts = collections.Counter(text.split())
...     return [elem for elem, _ in counts.most_common(5)]
...
>>> top5_words("""As the title says, I need to write a code that returns a list of 5 words (from an input string) that have the highest frequency. This is what I have so far""")
['that', 'a', 'I', 'the', 'have']
```

---

For the new requirement from comments -

> it seems there's still an issue when it comes to words with the same frequency, how would I get it to sort same frequency words alphabetically?

You can first get the list of all words and their counts and then use `sorted` such that sorted first sorts on the count and then on the element itself (so it gets sorted lexicographically, when the count is same). Example -

```
import collections
def top5_words(text):
    counts = collections.Counter(text.lower().split())
    return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(),key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))[:5]]
```

Demo -

```
>>> import collections
>>> def top5_words(text):
...     counts = collections.Counter(text.lower().split())
...     return [elem for elem, _ in sorted(counts.most_common(),key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))[:5]]
...
>>> top5_words("""As the title says, I need to write a code that returns a list of 5 words (from an input string) that have the highest frequency. This is what I have so far""")
['a', 'have', 'i', 'that', 'the']
```

Comment: That worked almost* perfectly - it seems there's still an issue when it comes to words with the same frequency, how would I get it to sort same frequency words alphabetically?

Comment: Glad I could be helpful . :)